# How do I properly map Postgres Array to Java @Entity?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

In my Postgres Table **Main table**I have a column that is ArrayList, **region_id_list**, that looks like this:
{1, 2}. This column refferes to another table, which is called **Regions**.
In my Java code, I have this Region class specified as @Entity and @Table, and I need to map it to another @Entity class, So when I get my MainTable Entity, I could include **Regions** list in it.

I've tried using:

- @ManyToOne
- @ElementCollection
- @CollectionTable
  But everytime I run it - I get **bad value long : {1, 2}**.

I have a similar output, but in this case orgDistrictsId reffers to the single-value column, not a ArrayList.

```
          "orgDistrictsId": {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "123"
        
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to give a clear answer. Regardless, I think you may be missing some major SQL and JPA/Hibernate knowledge. Using a column of an array list doesn't create a relationship to another table. This defeats the power of relational databases.

Postgres' use of storing array list data types is not to create relationships between tables, but allow you to save and fetch array objects, in your case Java, easier. I'm not the biggest fan as this type of database data type can be messy, but it has its place.

Based on what you've described, you actually have a many-to-many relationship. One `MainTable` entity can have many regions and it sounds like one `Region` entity can associate with many `MainTable` entities.
For a many-to-many relationship you're best off using a bridge table between the two. So you'd have your `MainTable` entities in one table and your `Region` entities in another. You'd then have a bridge table of two columns. One column represents the unique id of the `MainTable` row and the other column would be the unique id of the `Region` table. This type of setup allows you to not be repeating unnecessary data. This also allows you to lean heavily on JPA/Hibernate's ability to understand `@ManyToMany` relationships and setup entities to easily populate.

Table names are also important to consider. They should have a meaningful name. Also semantically, you should call it `Region` not `Regions`. I know it seems small, but the concept of a table is to have multiple rows. So its assumed that the table name should be singular and represent many entities.

I would recommend getting some knowledge on relational databases so you understand the concept of how relationships are established between tables (mentioned above bridge table, but one-to-many and many-to-one use the concept of primary key and foreign key to create the relationship). Also do some specific learning on JPA/Hibernate once you have a better understanding of SQL design.